# Getting weird indentation with Shift-o in vim

Tags: vim

I'm just getting used to Vim, I'm really enjoying it right now. But I'm having a weird issue right now with `shift-o`. I feel like it should stay in line but when I use the command it tabs like 2 times to the left. Here is a screenshot:

Before Shift-o:

[image]

After Shift-o

[image]

As you can see it does a jump forward. I'd like it to stay in place and just go up. Any way I can do this?

### Vimrc:

```
set tabstop=2
set number
set nowrap
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
set smartindent
```

to your `.vimrc`. From `:h smartindent`:

```
                 *'smartindent'* *'si'* *'nosmartindent'* *'nosi'*
'smartindent' 'si'  boolean (default off)
            local to buffer
            {not in Vi}
            {not available when compiled without the
            |+smartindent| feature}
    Do smart autoindenting when starting a new line.  Works for C-like
    programs, but can also be used for other languages.  'cindent' does
    something like this, works better in most cases, but is more strict,
    see |C-indenting|.  When 'cindent' is on or 'indentexpr' is set,
    setting 'si' has no effect.  'indentexpr' is a more advanced
    alternative.
```

You should probably consider also adding

```
set autoindent
```

to your `.vimrc`. This is not necessary, just recommended. In fact, the vim-help itself recommends this if you scroll down further:

```
    Normally 'autoindent' should also be on when using 'smartindent'.
    An indent is automatically inserted:
    - After a line ending in '{'.
    - After a line starting with a keyword from 'cinwords'.
    - Before a line starting with '}' (only with the "O" command).
```